# Start new activity using Gesture when i draw letter T

Tags: android

I am developing an sample application which consists of Gesture, I have gone through some sample code also, I can't understand it.

a) In my application when i Draw a Letter (T) or (Q) i need to start an New Activity.

b) I have created res/raw folder, how i should keep gestures in that.

c) I have some sample code which i am pasting below for reference.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gestureResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gestureresult);
        //To load the gestures into your application GestureLibrary is used.gestures are stored under res/raw/gestures.
        gestureLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gesture);
        if (!gestureLibrary.load()) {
            finish();
        }
        // A gesture overlay acts as a simple drawing board on which the user can draw his gestures.
        gestureOverlayView = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(gesturePerformedListener);
    }

    OnGesturePerformedListener gesturePerformedListener = new OnGesturePerformedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView view, Gesture gesture) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<Prediction> prediction = gestureLibrary.recognize(gesture);
            if(prediction.size() > 0){
                System.out.println("prediction::>"+prediction);
                gestureResult.setText(prediction.get(0).name);
            }
        }};
```

On following line **gestureLibrary.load()** activity is getting finished because gestures are not able to load. following exception i have received in my log.

```
05-15 13:17:06.027: D/ddm-heap(3012): Got feature list request
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012): Could not load the gesture library from raw resource com.gesture.testgesture:raw/gesture
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012): java.io.EOFException
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:395)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at android.gesture.GestureStore.load(GestureStore.java:285)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at android.gesture.GestureLibraries$ResourceGestureLibrary.load(GestureLibraries.java:132)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at com.gesture.testgesture.GestureIdentifierActivity.onCreate(GestureIdentifierActivity.java:28)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
05-15 13:17:06.257: D/Gestures(3012):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
```

and finally how to switch from one activity to another activity by using drawing the Gesture letter T and Q.